# NOVICE SQL What is the format for a plain-text file representing a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have create a table in postgresql:

```
 mydb=# create table weather(
 mydb(# city varchar(80),
 mydb(# temp_lo int,
 mydb(# temp_hi int,
 mydb(# prcp real,
 mydb(# date date
 mydb(# );
```

Then I created a text file called  dbtest.txt which looks like this:

```
New York    45  75  3.2 1994-11-27
Columbus    67  88  4.5 1998-12-23
```

When I type in the command:

```
mydb=# COPY weather FROM '/home/nicholas/Documents/dbtest.txt';
```

I get this:

> ERROR:  missing data for column "temp_lo" CONTEXT:  COPY weather, line
>   3: ""

So what is the proper format for my text file so that postgresql can add the data to the table?

Comment: Looks like you have some extra linefeed at the the end of your text file?

Answer (score 1):

Deleted line feed! Worked . I had third line with nothing on it, the copy command tried to import that empty line.